# URL string not submitting in Arduino IDE with ESP8266

Tags: c#, arduino, esp8266

I'm trying to implement my ddns auto-updating device on ESP8266. The first GET line: `http.begin("http..myhost.com.br/ip/index.php"); //HTTP`
retrieves my wan IP from  my host, and the second should build a URL to submit it to a PHP script that writes it to a txt file on host.

```
String url = "http.../ip/input.php?ip=" + payload;
http.begin(url);
```

When I write the URL directly in the `http.begin(http...187.37.128.155)` it works fine, but when I include the URL string with the appended payload string with WAN IP it does not submit. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

#define USE_SERIAL Serial
ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;

void setup() {
  USE_SERIAL.begin(9600);
  USE_SERIAL.setDebugOutput(true);
  USE_SERIAL.println();
  USE_SERIAL.println();
  USE_SERIAL.println();
  for(uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
    USE_SERIAL.printf("[SETUP] WAIT %d...\n", t);
    USE_SERIAL.flush();
    delay(1000);
  }
  WiFiMulti.addAP("ssid", "password");
}

void loop() {
  // wait for WiFi connection
  if((WiFiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) {
    HTTPClient http;
    USE_SERIAL.print("[HTTP] begin...\n");
    // configure traged server and url
    http.begin("http://..../ip/index.php"); //HTTP
    USE_SERIAL.print("[HTTP] GET...\n");
    // start connection and send HTTP header
    int httpCode = http.GET();
    // httpCode will be negative on error
    if(httpCode > 0) {
      // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
      USE_SERIAL.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);
      // file found at server
      if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
        String payload = http.getString();
        String url = "http://myhost.../ip/input.php?ip=" + payload;
        USE_SERIAL.print(url);
        USE_SERIAL.print("[HTTP] write...\n");
        // configure traged server and url
        http.begin(url);
        USE_SERIAL.print("[HTTP] write...\n");
        // start connection and send HTTP header
        int httpCode = http.GET();
        // httpCode will be negative on error
        if(httpCode > 0) {
          // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
          USE_SERIAL.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);
          // file found at server
          if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
            String payload = http.getString();
            USE_SERIAL.println(payload);
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      USE_SERIAL.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
    }
    http.end();
  }
  delay(10000);
```

TERMINAL RESPONSE:

```
[HTTP] begin...
[HTTP] GET...
[HTTP] GET... code: 200
http..myhost../ip/input.php?ip=187.37....
[HTTP] write...
[HTTP] write...
```

Comment: Why do you have ... everywhere?

Comment: because this website sucks, not permitting to ad full url adresses http:// www.website.com I had to change for ... so it can publish the question. Do you have any clue why it is not accepting my string? When I place a full URL  http.begin("http://myhost.../ip/input.php?ip=192.168.100.2") instead of http.begin(url); It works fine. But when adding the IP from the previous GET it does not work.